# Have a chunk of a lacquered guitar that got ding'd out, can I use wood filler on it?

Tags: wood-repair

[image]I haven't worked with lacquered wood before, so I have a guitar where there's a chip/chunk that came off (part of a larger crack repair). Is that something I can use wood filler to fill up? Would I have to sand down the lacquer first (i.e., can wood filler stick to the lacquer)?

And then, after I fill it, I want to re-spray lacquer over it, so also would want to ask if wood filler can take lacquer paint or not.

Thanks!

Comment: Your issue here is really more complex than can be well covered here. The simple answers are that yes of course you can use wood filler (this is always an individual choice) and yes you can lacquer over it. But it's unlikely you'll get a good aesthetic repair with filler of any kind without more work. Plus there are quite a few types to choose from (see previous Answers) with the likelihood being that you'll either A, need to mix to get a decent colour match or B, fill then stain/colour, prior to the lacquer. Realise you're going to need to sand to flush the repair, regardless of filler type.

Comment: Given what you're working with here, I think you'd be much better off posting a question like this on a luthier or specifically a guitar-making forum where you can get into a back-and-forth with respondents, who are much more likely to have directly relevant experience re. any strength concerns there might be, and how to (as much as possible) end up with a seamless repair. You'll want to give them more info than you've provided here for context, and provide numerous photos so they can assess the damage better.

Comment: Probably far more important than the _aesthetics_ resulting from the repair work is the _sound quality_ of the repair work. "Any old wood filler" will, I'd imagine, change the sound of the guitar, and I can't imagine that it would be for the better.

Comment: @Graphus can i use wood filler directly on the spot or should i sand down the lacquered areas around it for better adhesion? if it were just regular wood?

Comment: You really want to address this in a more holistic way so I would advise following my above recommendation and ask in a different venue. This isn't something you want to do half-right, do it the right way the first time and you shouldn't have to touch it again for years.

Comment: @james I would *strongly* recommend talking to a luthier before trying anything. There are lots of different types of wood filler, and most likely the crack will need to be prepared before filling it. Guitar makers are definitely the people you want to be talking to, and like Graphus implied, Stack Exchange isn't really a forum for back-and-forth.

Comment: @FreeMan, from the one image we can't be sure of the location but I worry this is somewhere on the neck so obviously structural issues are also a big potential concern!

Comment: Now that you say that @Graphus, I see "neck" there. When I first saw it, I thought that was the sounding board and we were looking through the hole into the guitar body. Either way, this just isn't the right place with the right collection of knowledge for _this_ type of repair.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.